Menu is not showing when I run my app in android studio
I created the menu directory inside res to create main_menu.xml after creating the xml file for the menu I added 2 items. These items are just 2 icons with a title & id. I used @override method of onCreateOptionMenu to show my items in the app. Unfortunately, the items are not there when I run my app! What should I do make them visible in the app
These images contain my MainActivity.java & main_menu.xml code. I haven't touched activity_main.xml!
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/CUacpMer.png)
These images have design view of main_menu.xml & the output which I'm getting when I run my app.
[enter image description here](https://i.senter image description herestatic.net/gw1owWbI.png)

Please post code as code-formatted text, not as an image. Otherwise the question and its answers won't help future visitors. Otherwise it is hard to cut / copy / paste and try to run your code. Best if you can create and post a [mre] program with your question. Please review the [ask], [tour] and [help] for more information.

First you have to use custom toolbar or noactinbar them.
I recommend to use a custom toolbar in XML
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

Make sure you have used NoActonBar them.
You have to set te actionbar to toolbar
Add below code to oncreate
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Then your code will work fine
Let me know if any issue happened
